# Symmetric functions and regularity (II)

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis

My previous question (where  [$n=2$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61720)) was a bit too naive. I think that this one, which is the one being of genuine interest to me, is more involved.

Let $f=\mathbb R^n\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be a symmetric function:
$$f(x^\sigma)=f(x),\qquad\forall\sigma\in\frak S_n,$$
where $x^\sigma:=(x_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma(n)})$.
There exists a unique function $F$, defined on the image of $\mathbb R^n$ under the map $x\mapsto (p_1,\ldots,p_n)$, where $p_j$ is the elementary symmetric polynomial of degree $j$, such that
$$f(x)=F(p_1,\ldots,p_n).$$

> What is the regularity of $F$ ? Does $f\in\mathcal C^r$ imply $F\in\mathcal C^{r/n}$ and not more ?

*Edit*. By $\mathcal C^s$-regularity on a closed domain, one means as usual that the function under consideration is the restriction of a $\mathcal C^s$-function defined on an open super-set.

Comment: In general the boundary of the domain of $F$ is singular. How is the regularity defined?